# Grails - IntelliJIdea9 Strange problem with packages

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, package

I'm having some trouble on a checked out project here at work.

I have a class called `GridBuilder`, which is located in a package called `com.ent.proj.utils.grid`

```
package com.ent.proj.utils.grid

import grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion
import org.hibernate.Criteria


class GridBuilder {
}
```

The word grid in the package declaration is marked in red, and reads `Cannot solve symbol grid`

This is the directory structure:

```
grailsapp--
           utils---
                  com---
                      ent---
                           proj---
                                 utils---
                                       grid---
                                          GridBuilder.groovy
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 9  as an IDE. I see this file in the project view, but not  in the Grails view.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

## update

Ran `$grails run-app` from command line, and the app. started OK. Maybe its an IntelliJIdea issue ?

Comment: did you declare grails-app/utils as a source folder in 'Project structure|Modules'?

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Please post this as an answer so I can upvote it + select it.

Comment: Hi @Tom, Me also come across the same problem. But when I declare `utils` as `source folder` it doesn't solved. Anything special to do in `IntelliJIdea 10.0.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you declare grails-app/utils as a source folder in 'Project structure|Modules'?

Comment: Hi @Stefan Armbruster, Me also come across the same problem. But when I declare `utils` as `source folder` it doesn't solved. Anything special to do in `IntelliJIdea 10.0.2`

Comment: try 'invalidate caches' in IntelliJ, this helps sometimes when it does not behave as expected - but be sure to have a mug of coffee on your desk - rebuilding the caches takes a fairly amount of time ;-)